# Date displaying differently on different servers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When i run the following query on my desktop

```
Select to_char(join_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
From students
group by to_char(join_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

I get the following output:

```
23-Oct-2012
25-Oct-2012
23-Oct-2012
23-Oct-2012
23-Oct-2012
26-Oct-2012
23-Oct-2012
24-Oct-2012
23-Oct-2012
```

But if i run it on a different server, the output comes out as:

```
23-Oct. -2012
25-Oct. -2012
23-Oct. -2012
23-Oct. -2012
23-Oct. -2012
26-Oct. -2012
23-Oct. -2012
24-Oct. -2012
23-Oct. -2012
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? 
The second server is running in a different country from me so its regional settings could be different.

Update:

NLS_DATE_FORMAT is DD-Mon-RRRR on both servers.

Comment: What is the output if you do a `to_char(date_column,'DD-MM-YYYY')` in the second server?

Comment: @Annjawn - The output comes out in the following format - 11-07-2007

Comment: The month in your original post is `October`, but the output of `to_char` shows `07`?? That's weird.... Can you try this - `to_char(date_column,'DD-MM-YYYY BC')` and see the output.

Comment: No thats just an example of the output. The month is correct i just picked one entry in the result that came back :)

Comment: If that's the case then you can probably use `to_date(to_char(date_column,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')`. I know that it's a way around the problem, but with this much info there is very little for me to identify what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

When oracle retrieve a date field from database and **show it to you, a implicitit cast conversion is made**. The format pattern for this conversion is set in oracle configuration. [Quoting oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm):

> The default date format for an Oracle date value is derived from the
>   NLS_DATE_FORMAT and NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE initialization parameters

If NLS_DATE_FORMAT is DD-Mon-RRRR on both servers **check NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE**.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mistype the code as:

```
select to_char(join_date,'dd-mon.-yyyy') from students;
```

That will give the results:

```
23-Oct.-2012
```

Answer (score 1):

As danihp suggests, the difference is probably down to the `NLS_LANGUAGE` setting, which is probably derived from a higher NLS parameter. You can override this to get consistent results - though that isn't necessarily a good idea - as described in the [globalisation support guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#sthref175). Running these queries should produce consistent results on the two servers (guessing that one of yours is French from the data you showed):

```
select to_char(join_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=FRENCH')
from students ...;

select to_char(join_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
from students ...;
```

Underlying the confusion is perhaps what you expect `MON` to represent. As noted in the [SQL reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements004.htm#sthref407), `MON` is the 'abbreviated name of month'; that means it is not necessarily a three-character abbreviation. How the full month name is abbreviated is dependent on the NLS settings.

In English all the month names can be abbreviated to three characters unambiguously:

```
select level as l,
    to_char(to_date(level, 'MM'), 'Month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
    to_char(to_date(level, 'MM'), 'Mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
from dual
connect by level <= 12
order by 1

         L TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LEVEL,'MM'),'MONTH', TO_CHAR(TO_D
---------- ------------------------------------ ------------
         1 January                              Jan
         2 February                             Feb
         3 March                                Mar
         4 April                                Apr
         5 May                                  May
         6 June                                 Jun
         7 July                                 Jul
         8 August                               Aug
         9 September                            Sep
        10 October                              Oct
        11 November                             Nov
        12 December                             Dec
```

In French that's not the case:

```
select level as l,
    to_char(to_date(level, 'MM'), 'Month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=FRENCH'),
    to_char(to_date(level, 'MM'), 'Mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=FRENCH')
from dual
connect by level <= 12
order by 1;

         L TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LEVEL,'MM'),'MONTH', TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LEVE
---------- ------------------------------------ --------------------
         1 Janvier                              Janv.
         2 Février                              Févr.
         3 Mars                                 Mars
         4 Avril                                Avr.
         5 Mai                                  Mai
         6 Juin                                 Juin
         7 Juillet                              Juil.
         8 Août                                 Ao
         9 Septembre                            Sept.
        10 Octobre                              Oct.
        11 Novembre                             Nov.
        12 Décembre                             Déc.
```

Clearly, using three-letter abbreviations would pose difficulties for Juin and Juillet. Presumably denoting the abbreviation with a period is a cultural thing, and with some months needing four characters to be distinctive, that bumps the `MON` format length up to five characters.

It may be slightly surprising that the format model keeps that as fixed width, so you have a space in the middle for the shorter abbreviations, as in your original data. I'm sure that could be argued either way though, and it seems to be applied consistently. I'm not aware of any way of stopping that automatically.